# Get taxa within an iNaturalist area or project using pyinaturalist

Tags: python

I set up projects on iNaturalist and I want to get a list of the current taxa found in those projects.
I tried:

```
from pyinaturalist import *

Bad_Durkheim = get_observations(project_id = "bad-durkheim-exkursion")
Species = [get_taxa(obs) for obs in Bad_Durkheim["results"]]
```

which resulted in

```
HTTPError: 414 Client Error: Request-URI Too Large for url: https://api.inaturalist.org/v1/taxa?q=%7B%27quality_gr...
```

I am not sure how to use this API, maybe someone has an explanation?
Also, I wondered why `Bad_Durkheim["results"]` is a list of 30, when there were more observations. If there is a limit of 30, how can it be changed?

**Edit**

This appears to get me a step further:

```
from pyinaturalist import *

Bad_Durkheim = get_observations(project_id = "bad-durkheim-exkursion")
Species = [obs["taxon"]["name"] for obs in Bad_Durkheim["results"]]
```

When I ran

```
Species = [obs for obs in Bad_Durkheim["results"]]
Species[0]["taxon"]["name"]
```

to test it, it worked in case `Species[0]`, however the loop failed with `TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem: Some entries didn't have the requested attributes, since they were listed as "unidentified".

Solution:

```
import pyinaturalist as pyn

Bad_Durkheim = pyn.get_observations(project_id = "bad-durkheim-exkursion",
                                identified = True)
Species = [obs["taxon"]["name"] for obs in Bad_Durkheim["results"]]
```